# ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered Django FormTools Wizard

Tags: python, django, django-formtools

views.py

```
FORMS = [("customer", CustomerModelForm),
         ("supplier", SupplierModelForm),
         ("brand", BrandMasterModelForm)]


TEMPLATES = {"customer": "add_customer.html",
             "supplier": "supplier_master",
             "brand": "add_brand.html"}
        
class MultiStepWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
        return render(self.request, "dashboard_inventory.html", {"data":form_data})
```

urls.py

```
path('manage_sales/', MultiStepWizard.as_view(FORMS), name="MultiStepWizard")
```

forms.py

```
class CustomerModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('name','address','contact','email','state','gstin','pan')
        
class SupplierModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = ('name','address','city','manager','contact')
        widgets = {
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'city':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'manager':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'contact':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            
            }

class BrandMasterModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BrandMaster
        fields=('brand_name', 'suppliername')
        widgets={'brand_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),'suppliername':forms.Select(attrs={'id':'choicewa','class': 'form-control','required': 'true'}),

        }
```

I'm trying to use formtool to save multistep forms with my own templates.
But I am getting error

```
ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered Django FormTools Wizard
```

While saving first form, then unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below line in html form

{{ wizard.management_form }}